# Inheriting C# Tuple<T, T> while adding value checks to the constructor.

Tags: c#, inheritance, tuples

I am not sure how to phrase the question better. I searched for it and did not find much of an answer, whether in Stack Overflow or elsewhere. Everything I got was how terrible the `Tuple` type is and how I should avoid doing that at all costs.

Anyway, the program I am working on, essentially, models a house with the rooms in it as some sort of Graph. To represent the rooms that should be adjacent to each other (and edge, or an `Adjacency`), I am using a `Tuple<Room, Room>` . However, every time I create that `Tuple` I go through checks to make sure the same two rooms are always in the same order. So if this was my class

```
public class Adjacency : Tuple<Room, Room>
{ 
    public Adjacency(Room item1, Room item2)
    {
    }
}
```

I need `Adjacency(Room1, Room2);` and  `Adjacency(Room2, Room1);` to always produce the same object. I am currently doing that by checking *before* I create the `Tuple` using `Tuple.Create`, but the code seems a bit of a mess at the moment and I am trying to abstract by inheriting from `Tuple<Room, Room>` and doing the checks in the constructor. (However since the base constructor executes first I can't find a way to do that).

The code I want to simplify/abstract is what follows, all currently in class `House`:

```
    public List<Tuple<Room, Room>> Adjacencies { get; private set; }

    public void PairRooms(Room r1, Room r2)
    {
        if(r1.UniqueID == r2.UniqueID)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot pair a room with itself.");

        foreach(var pair in Adjacencies)
            if((r1.UniqueID == pair.Item1.UniqueID && r2.UniqueID == pair.Item2.UniqueID)
                || (r1.UniqueID == pair.Item2.UniqueID && r2.UniqueID == pair.Item1.UniqueID))
                throw new Exception("Pair already paired.");

        var adjacentRooms = r1.NumericID < r2.NumericID ? Tuple.Create(r1, r2) : Tuple.Create(r2, r1);
        Adjacencies.Add(adjacentRooms);
        Console.WriteLine($"{r1.Name}, {r2.Name} are paired");
    }

    public IList<Room> GetAdjacentRooms(Room room)
    {
        var rooms = new List<Room>();
        foreach(var pair in Adjacencies)
            if(pair.Item1.UniqueID == room.UniqueID)
                rooms.Add(pair.Item2);
            else if(pair.Item2.UniqueID == room.UniqueID)
                rooms.Add(pair.Item1);

        return rooms;
    }

    public bool AreAdjacent(Room r1, Room r2)
    {
        foreach(var pair in Adjacencies)
            if((r1.UniqueID == pair.Item1.UniqueID && r2.UniqueID == pair.Item2.UniqueID)
                || (r1.UniqueID == pair.Item2.UniqueID && r2.UniqueID == pair.Item1.UniqueID))
                return true;

        return false;
    }
```

I know the code is a mess and I am using two ID's for the objects (one is a GUID and the other is just based on a static population counter), but that's not the part I am having trouble with.

I am using the `PairRooms` method all over the `House` constructor, and the other two methods are used by algorithms operating on the house (to shuffle the rooms about and whatnot.)

Thanks for your help.

PS. would it be a viable alternative to have `Tuple<Room, Room>` a private property of `Adjacency` instead of it being the base class ?

Comment: If all objects are promised to enter the Adjacency constructor with an ID (the GUID or the static population counter), and if I may make the assumption that your IDs won't change (they shouldn't), couldn't you just reorder them based on the value of the ID?

Comment: Tuple is more of a convenience class, so that if you need a class for grouping multiple things, you don't have to create one. But if you're creating your class already, it doesn't make sense to inherit from Tuple. Just add two properties to your class.

Comment: @NexTerren the question is how do I do that inside the constructor?

Comment: If you want to use Linq, this should do the trick: var ordered = new List<Room>() { r1, r2 }; ordered = ordered.OrderBy(aRoom => aRoom.UniqueID); Tuple.Create(ordered[0], ordered[1]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ensure reference equality for your Adjacency objects by hiding the constructor and providing a static method to create Adjacency objects.

```
public class Adjacency : Tuple<Room, Room>
{ 
    private static readonly List<Adjacency> identityMap = new List<Adjacency>();
    private Adjacency(Room item1, Room item2)
    {
    }

    public static Get (Room a, Room b)
    {
       // look through the identity map and return a matching value
       // if none, call the constructor
    }
}
```

If you also implement `IEquatable<Adjacency>` this gets even easier. And if you care about concurrency use a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,Adjacency>` for the identity map.

PS I use a graph for representing this kind of information (and more) in my system [here](http://blog.abodit.com/2014/11/home-automation-systems-graph/).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late. You can use a bool function and a cache bool (to avoid calling it twice) and call the base constructor, swapping the two arguments' places based on the function's return.

```
public class OrderConsistentSameTypeTuple<T> : Tuple<T, T>
{
    public OrderConsistentSameTypeTuple(T item1, T item2) : this(item1, item2, false) { }

    private OrderConsistentSameTypeTuple(T item1, T item2, bool swappedConstrArgs)
        : base(
              (swappedConstrArgs = swapConstrArgs(item1, item2))
                ? item2 : item1,
              swappedConstrArgs ? item1 : item2) { }

    private static bool swapConstrArgs(T item1, T item2)
    {
        //a true return here will swap base constructor arguments' places
    }
}
```